# Set up a MySQL slave using mysqldump to get the initial data

Tags: mysql, replication, innodb, mysqldump, myisam

I have a master database which already has some data in it. The tables in the master database include both MyISAM and InnoDB engines. Now I want use ***mysqldump*** to dump the initial data of my slave MySQL server. What parameter I should pass to mysqldump? Currently what I use is listed below.

```
mysqldump --host=localhost --user=root --password=pa4word --single-transaction --lock-all-tables --master-data=1 mydb > result.sql
```

Is this command OK? I don't know whether this is suit to my environment(both MyISAM and InnoDB engine tables in one database).

Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are dumping a mysql database that has a mixture of InnoDB and MyISAM and you have scheduled downtime:

```
mysqldump -u... -p... --master-data=1 --single-transaction --flush-privileges --routines --triggers --all-databases > /root/mydata.sql
```

Since --opt is enabled by default, the following options are already enabled

- `--add-drop-table`
- `--add-locks`
- `--create-options`
- `--quick`
- `--lock-tables`
- `--set-charset`
- `--disable-keys`

If you are concerned about InnoDB/MyISAM together in the mysqldump and you want the database placed in a read-only state, try putting a read lock across all tables manually.

```
MYSQL_CONN="-hhostip -uusername -ppassword"
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -A -e"FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK; SELECT SLEEP(86400)" &
SEARCHING_FOR_SLEEP=0
while [ ${SEARCHING_FOR_SLEEP} -eq 0 ]
do
    sleep 3
    SEARCHING_FOR_SLEEP=`${MYSQL} ${MYSQL_CONN} -A -e"SHOW PROCESSLIST;" | grep -c "SELECT SLEEP(86400)"`
done
sleep 1
SLEEP_ID=`mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -A -e"SHOW PROCESSLIST;" | grep "SELECT SLEEP(86400)" | awk '{print $1}'`

mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} --master-data=2 --single-transaction --flush-privileges --routines --triggers --all-databases > /root/mydata.sql

mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -A -e"KILL ${SLEEP_ID}"
```

The reason this is better to do is that `--single-transaction` does not protect MyISAM from changing during the dump.

Before launching the mysqldump, make sure binary logging is enabled on the master. If it is not, do the following:

Step 01) Add this to /etc/my.cnf on the master

```
[mysqld]
log-bin=mysql-bin
```

Step 02) `service mysql restart`

This will enable binary logging on the master.

On the new slave, you can run the following command:

```
CHANGE MASTER TO
MASTER_HOST='IP of the master',
MASTER_PORT=3306,
MASTER_USER='whatever_username',
MASTER_PASSWORD='whatever_password',
MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000001',
MASTER_LOG_POS=107;
```

Make sure the rep_username exists in the master. If it does not, run this command on the master:

```
GRANT SELECT, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT
ON *.* TO 'whatever_username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'whatever_password';
```

Then do the mysqldump to /root/mydata.sql.

Move the /root/mydata.sql from the master to the slave.

Next, execute in the mysql client this command on the slave:

```
source /root/mydata.sql
```

This will load mysqldump in the slave and the set the correct log file and log position in /var/lib/mysql/master.info.

Finally, run `START SLAVE;` on the slave and mysql replication should get going.

Run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` to check replication status.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thank you very much RolandoMySQLDBA!!! You've answered a lot of my questions. You just like a kind and knowledgeable friend. I'm very much appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your requirement.***mysqldump*** has also other options.You can specify them using ***mysqldump*** ***--help*** and choose from there what parameters you require.

If you didn't want to give extra efforts this one is ok.

I basically use

```
mysqldump -uroot -proot --extended-insert --all-databases --add-drop-database --disable-keys --flush-privileges --quick --routines --triggers > all-databases.sql
```